# What is the best way to combine 2 or more fields as a Key in a Map, using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have been facing multiple requirements where I need to convert a List to Map, and in some cases I need to combine 2 fields as keys for that map, Previously I used the below solution -

```
Map<String, Integer> employeePairs = employees.stream().collect(HashMap<String, Integer>::new,
            (m, c) -> m.put(c.getFirstName() + " " + c.getLastName(), c.employeeId),
            (m, u) -> {
            });
```

I found a new way but that use a different package apache Pair the code looks like this-

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, Integer> employeePairs = employees.stream().collect(HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Integer>::new,
            (m, c) -> m.put(Pair.of(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName()), c.employeeId),
            (m, u) -> {
            });
    employeePairs.get(Pair.of("a1", "b1"));// way of accessing
```

Package -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Which is a better way? Or is there a more better way.

Comment: See also https://www.jeronimo.dev/composite-key-in-hashmaps/

Comment: Thanks that was a helpful information

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an extra library for using only `Pair` class,
you can use [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) for pairing two fields and to collect as map, it's better to use `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>, Integer> employeePairs =   
    employees.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                c -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName()),
                c -> c.employeeId
              ));
```

You can access data of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` using `.getKey()` and `.getValue()`

Comment: Does this not make the access more complicated?, I mean which looks more simple? The use of Pair.of or AbstractMap.SimpleEntry

Comment: If you don't want to use an extra library for using only `Pair` class, then this will be a good approach

Comment: @ISHANKUMARGHOSH The access to the key would depend on the queries you tend to operate upon. Further, if they were always to be represented as a concatenated `String`, even the first version shall work. But you should be aware of the uniqueness constraint based on `equals` of the type of the key you choose for the `Map`.

Comment: Since both values have the same type, `Arrays.asList(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName())` would be feasible too; this solution would also work with more elements. Java 9+ has `List.of(c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName())` which works even better. Or in the future, we will use `record Key(String firstName, String lastName) {}`…